# За что минусовать ответы на довольно глупые вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Участник задал довольно глупый вопрос. Ну я ответил. Да, согласен со @стас , но, как говорил я в комментарии, я сделал свое дело. Но за что минусовать? Это [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149657/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-while-%D0%B2-python)

Comment: Не минусовал, но мне кажется, что Ваш ответ не раскрывает тему. Вы привели код, но не объяснили, что он делает. Стоило бы рассказать новичку о синтаксической конструкции и её практическом применении. В идеале ещё хотелось бы видеть обоснованное использование `while` вместо `for` (но это я уже придираюсь).

Comment: А вообще у нас не принято минусовать правильные ответы на плохие вопросы.

Comment: То, что Ваш ответ помог автору вопроса — это замечательно (правда). Но у нас база знаний, и хотелось бы, чтобы ответ помог другим. А для этого он должен быть исчерпывающим.

Comment: @nomnoms12 хорошо, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Попробуем улучшить вопрос ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос, на который вы отвечали, разумеется оставляет желать лучшего. Однако, лично я вижу несколько потенциально проблематичных аспектов ответа на него:

1. Как уже было сказано в комментарии, в ответе приведен только код без всякого объяснения. Редко когда ответ, содержащий только код, является по-настоящему хорошим. Несмотря на то, что ответ четко отвечает на плохо поставленный вопрос (попросили привести пример - пример и приведен), на мой взгляд, не стоит давать таковых ответов. Либо голосовать за закрытие вопроса. Либо давать ответ по высоким стандартам: объяснение, что пример делает, синтаксис, потенциально как искать ответы на такие вопросы без посторонней помощи и т.д.
2. > Вы задаете простые вопросы! Вот обычный пример:

   Мне немного режет глаза фраза "вы задаете простые вопросы". Во-первых, она точно не принадлежит к ответу и, несколько, обижает. Мне бы не понравилось ее услышать в такой формулировке. Несмотря на то, что это правда, есть другие способы выражения этого: закрытие вопроса по соответствующей причине, игнорирование этого факта и предоставление исчерпывающего ответа, фокус на вопросе, а не на личности.

Ответы на "далекие от идеала" вопросы вещь сложная, и к ним стоит подходить тщательно. Здорово, что вы потратили время и, возможно, помогли автору вопроса. Но, возможно, стоило подойти чуть более внимательно к ответу, либо потратить время на уточнение\закрытие вопроса, или вообще на него не отвечать (этому тоже несложно подобрать разумное обоснование).

Comment: @Антон автор имеет возможность принять ваш ответ и проголосовать. Сообщество голосует по своим критериям, а не критериям автора.